# Confusion about Matrix Diagonalisation, Generalised Eigenvalue problem and Quadratic Forms (Lagrangian example)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, diagonalization, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm apologize on behalf of the length of this question but I really wanted to pinpoint where the problem lies

### Part One (nonessential)

The origin of the problem comes form a problem in physics which is to diagonalise a Lagrangian (a special kind of quadratic form) of the form
$$L=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}m_{ij}\dot{x}_i\dot{x}_j-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}k_{ij}x_ix_j=\frac{1}{2}\big(\dot{\vec{x}}|M\dot{\vec{x}}\big)-\frac{1}{2}\big(\vec{x}|K\vec{x}\big)$$

where
$\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\.\\.\\x_n \end{pmatrix}$ and $M=(m_{ij})$ and $K=(k_{ij})$, and where $M$ and $K$ is a positive definite symmetric matrices

the physicsy way of solving the problem would be to use the Euler-Lagrange equations to get $n$ differential equations of the second order, namely:
$$M\ddot{\vec{x}}+K\vec{x}=0$$
in matrix form, since $M$ is positive definite, then it is invertible, so we write
$$\ddot{\vec{x}}+M^{-1}K\vec{x}=0$$ 
now we wish to find some vector $\vec{a}$ that
$$\ddot{\vec{a}}+M^{-1}K\vec{a}=\ddot{\vec{a}}+\omega_a^2\vec{a}=0$$
$\vec{a}$ is aka the eigenvector with it's eigenvalue $\omega_a^2$. 
For this particular case the differential equation is easy to solve because it becomes the equation of the harmonic oscilator so
$$Q_1(t)=\vec{a}e^{i\omega_at}$$

this is effectively the process of diagonalising the matrix $M^-1K$ which we do via the standard Lin.Alg. method 
$$det(M^{-1}K-\lambda I)=0$$
since $M$ is positive definite $det(M)>0$ so by Binet-Cauchy
$$det(M)det(M^{-1}K-\lambda I)=0$$
In this way we find (let's say the system is non degenerate) we find all those $\omega_1^2,\omega_2^2...\omega_n^2$ and $\vec{a_1},...\vec{a_n}$ and finally all the special solutions $Q_1(t),Q_2(t),...Q_3(t)$ for those eigenvectors (aka Modes) 
the ''vectors'' in our ''solution space'' (as some physicist would say)
$$\{Q_1(t),...Q_n(t)\}$$
form a basis of our solution space, so any possible solution $x(t)$ can be represented as a linear combination of the vectors $Q_1(t)...Q_n(t)$
so we  can write $(C_i \in \mathbb{C})$

$$x(t)=C_1Q_1(t)+C_2Q_2(t)+...C_nQ_n(t)$$

where $C_i$ are determined from the initial conditions. so far so good, there has been no change of basis.

### Part Two

the second way to approach this is to go back to our Lagrangian

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}m_{ij}\dot{x}_i\dot{x}_j-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}k_{ij}x_ix_j=\frac{1}{2}\big(\dot{\vec{x}}|M\dot{\vec{x}}\big)-\frac{1}{2}\big(\vec{x}|K\vec{x}\big)$$

and ask: can we change the basis in such a way that both matrices $M$ and $K$ become orthogonal?
if we can$^{(*)}$, let's call those coordinates $q_i$ (what a coincidence) 
then we get a Lagrangian (quadratic form) of the type

$$L=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}m'_{ij}\delta_{ij}\dot{x_i}\dot{x_j}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j}k'_{ij}\delta_{ij}q_iq_j=\frac{1}{2}\big(\dot{\vec{q}}|D_M\dot{\vec{q}}\big)-\frac{1}{2}\big(\vec{q}|D_K\vec{q}\big)$$

This Langrangian gives us the equations of motion that are completely separated

$$
  \begin{pmatrix} m'_1 & & & \\  & ..& & \\& & & .. &  \\ & & & & m'_n \end{pmatrix} 
  \begin{pmatrix} \ddot{q_1(t)} \\ . \\.\\\ddot{q_n(t)} \end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix} k'_1 & & & \\  & ..& & \\& & & .. &  \\ & & & & k'_n \end{pmatrix} 
  \begin{pmatrix} q_1(t) \\ . \\.\\q_n(t) \end{pmatrix}=0
$$

which means that for every $q_i$ we get the solution $q_i(t)=Ce^{i\omega_it}$ ($\omega_i$ is $\sqrt(k'_i/m'_i)$ ofcourse)

so we basically got the same thing as in Part one. We write our solution $\vec{x}$ in the basis  of vectors $q_i$ which is equivalent to representing it as
$$x_i(t)=C_1a_{i1}q_1(t)+C_2a_{i2}q_2(t)+...C_na_{in}q_n(t)$$

We can write the whole of $\vec{x}$ as

$$\vec{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\.\\.\\x_n \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} C_1a_{11}q_1(t)+C_2a_{12}q_2(t)+...C_na_{1n}q_n(t) \\ C_1a_{21}q_1(t)+C_2a_{22}q_2(t)+...C_na_{2n}q_n(t) \\.\\.\\C_1a_{n1}q_1(t)+C_2a_{n2}q_2(t)+...C_na_{nn}q_n(t) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} &a_{12} & & \\a_{21}& a_{22}& & \\& & & .. &  \\ & & & & a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} C_1q_1(t) \\ C_2q_2(t) \\.\\.\\C_nq_n(t) \end{pmatrix}=A\vec{Q}$$

now $C_1,...C_n$ are initial conditions in the system with basis $q_i$ (I think?)

so the matrix $A$ composed of our eigenvectors transforms $\{q_i\} \to \{x_i\}$
so our initial change of basis was actually $A^{-1}$

all quiet on the western front

### Part Three (problems start emerging)

in part two$^{(*)}$ we assumed such a change of basis can be done a then found the matrix $A^-1$ that was the transformation we were looking for.
I will now try to prove that this kind of transformation can always be done (and get confused along the way..)

We can diagonalise $M$ with and orthogonal matrix $U$ because $M$ is real and symmetries, so:

$$M=S^TD_MS$$

now since $M$ is positive definite it has positive eigenvalues so there exist a matrix $S_{ij}=\frac{\delta_{ij}}{\sqrt{\mu_i}}$ (where $\mu_i$ are eigenvalues of the matrix $D_M$)

we can see that the matrix $US$ transform the matrix $M$ in to an unit matrix

$$(US)^TM(US)=I$$

The matrix $(US)^TK(US)$ is still symmetric because

$$k'_{ij}=\sum_{k,l}(US)_{ik}^Tk_{kl}(US)_{lj}=\sum_{k,l}(US)_{ki}k_{kl}(US)_{jl}^T=\sum_{k,l}(US)_{jl}^Tk_{lk}(US)_{ki}=k'_{ji}$$

and since $K'$ is symmetric there exist a orthogonal matrix $V$ such that
$V^TK'V=(USV)^TK(USV)$

This proves that the matrix $(USV)$ diagonalises $M$ and $K$ simultaneously.

Finally for the questions!

1.) What are we actually doing with $S$? Is it a change of basis of some kind that shortens each basis vector by the factor  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_i}}$ ?
is it a transformation at all?
Does this mean that we have effectively changed all the eigenvalues to 1!? (which make no sense) 
or does that mean that it is a vector of our basis who, when multiplied by it's eigenvalue gives 1?

is the matrix $A$ from the end of part two equal to the matrix $(USV)$?

Does part three mean that we can reduce every matrix (that is positive definite) to a identity matrix, if yes why? if no, why not? and what does it mean geometrically?

In part 3, are the eigenvectors of $M$ and $K$ the same vectors or are they different but are just diagonisable by the same transformation? Is this even possible?

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/230322/103567)
answer there is bascically a connection between part two and part one, where @MichaelSeifert defines the vector $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{v'}$ and says the basis vectors may not necessarily be orthogonal (mean the basis of vectors that diagonalise the Lagrangian) 
$\vec{v}$ and $\vec{v'}$ are not the eigenvalues of the same matrix?
What are they, what do they represent?
Doesn't [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode) clearly state that Normal modes are orthogonal?
shouldn't this also follow from the [Principal axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem)?
why are they always orthogonal? (proof reference?)

I hope my questions are meaningful and understandable, and again sorry for the length of the post, but I'm just super confused and can't get my head around this for a two weeks now...

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two types of "diagonalization". One is for a linear transformation, the other is for a quadratic form.

If I didn't misunderstand, you're diagonalizing two quadratic forms simultaneously. The geometric meaning of this procedure is redefining measure, which is the inner product of basis vectors. We can usually denote it as $[(e_i,e_j)]$. It will completely determine the value of quadratic forms, for example we can write 
$$x^TAx = \sum_{i,j}x_ix_je_i^TAe_j$$
where $x_i$ is the ith entry of $x$. The usual inner product is $$x^Tx =  \sum_{i,j}x_ix_je_i^Te_j $$, so we have defined a new inner product $<e_i, e_j> = e_i^TAe_j$.

If there exists invertible $P$ such that $P^TAP=B$, we say matrix A and B are congruent. Every positive definite matrix is congruent to $I$. And every positive definite matrix is symmetric so we have $T$ orthogonal such that $T^TAT=T^{-1}AT=D$, where $D$ is diagonal.

So to do the diagonalization of $M$ and $K$, we can first choose $P$ such that $P^TMP=I$. Then choose $T$ such that $T$ is orthogonal and $T^T(P^TKP)T = D$. Let $Q = PT$, $x = Qy$, then we have 
$$\dot{x}^TM\dot{x}+x^TKx=\dot{y}^T\dot{y}+y^TDy$$

In this context, $x=Qy$ is just a substitution that changes measure, and has nothing to do with eigenvectors(which comes from linear transformation context).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by saying that $x=Qy$ is a change of measure? do you mean redefining the scalar product by which we construct the quadratic form, and if so, how exactly is this a change of measure. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @AlexandarSolženjicin The measure is just $[e_i, e_j]$ which tells you what the inner product should be.

Comment: so you are saying that by rescaling the vectors we are, in fact, re-definig the inner product?

Comment: Yes. In one way you can say the measure matrix is changed. Or you can view it just as a substitution, which suffices to simplify calculation.

Comment: I have edited it, is that clear now?